# How to select a Radio Button based on EmployeeNumber from a List of EmployeeDataList

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, frontend

Iam Having List of EmployeeData,with EmpNo&EmpName.so My problem is iam not able to check the radio button as iam using ng-repeat for list.

i tried using ng-model="checked" & ng-checked="true" but it doesnt worked.

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in  unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.EmployeePaginationList" >

                                                        <td><input type="radio"                     
                                                            name="selectedObj"
                                                            ng-model="unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.employeeChecked"                                                          
                                                            data-ng-click="unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.selectIdeRep(employee)"                                                  
                                                            ></td>                                                      
                                                            <td>{{employee.EmployeeNo}} </td>
                                                                <td>{{employee.FirstName}} {{employee.LastName}}</td>
                                                                <!-- <td>{{employee.Email}}</td> -->
                                                                <td>{{employee.departmentName}}</td>
                                                                <td>{{employee.plantName}}</td>
                                                                <td>{{employee.divisionName}}</td>
                                                                <td>{{employee.businessUnitName}}</td> 
                                                </tr>
```

```
  unsafeActionService.viewUnsafeAction(obj).then(function (response) {
               if(response.data != null){ 
                   unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.unsafeActData = response.data;
                   console.log(unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.EEmployeeList);
                   unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.EEmployeeList.forEach(function(Element){
                       console.log(Element);
                       if(unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.unsafeActData.reportedNo == Element.EmployeeNo){
                           console.log(unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.unsafeActData.reportedNo);
                           console.log(Element.EmployeeNo);
                           unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.employeeChecked = true; 
                       }else{
                           unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.employeeChecked = false; 
                       }

                   })
```

i want to select a radio button based on employee-No from the Employee-list.

if the "employee-No == employee-No of Employee-list" , then the particular radio button should be selected, like check-boxes[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAD3R.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your radio button a value/ngValue so that it knows when to select that item.  From what you have there:

```
<td><input type="radio" name="selectedObj"
       ng-model="unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.selectedEmployee"
       ng-value="employee"                                                          
       data-ng-click="unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.selectIdeRep(employee)">
</td>
```

This will setup the update based on radio button selection or manual setting of unsafeActionIntimationCntrl.selectedEmployee = employees[X].

Edit: Just wanted to follow up with a little sample. There are some differences (mainly the ng-model requiring $parent) but it should be close. https://plnkr.co/edit/ILPlvdo7OxWRqjY0IRwF?p=preview